NodeJS -> SQL Server 2019 connection issue
I am trying to create a test signup page. I have been able to get everything working and it appears that the server is properly connecting.
Here is my code:
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;  
    var config = {  
        server: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',  //update me
        authentication: {
            type: 'default',
            options: {
                trustServerCertificate: true 
            }
        },
        options: {
            encrypt: false,
            database: 'XXXXXXX',  //update me
            port: XXXXXXX
        }
    };  

    var connection = new Connection(config);  

    connection.connect(); 

    connection.on('connect', function(err) {  
        // If no error, then good to proceed.
        console.log("Connected"); 
        ExecuteFunction();

    });

    connection.on('debug', function(err) { console.log('debug:', err);});
    
    var Request = require('tedious').Request  
    var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES; 

        app.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
            res.sendFile("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        });

        function ExecuteFunction() {        
        // Route to handle signup request
        app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
            const { username, email, password } = req.body;

        var request = new Request('INSERT INTO Users (Username, Email, PasswordHash) VALUES (@username, @email, @password)', function(err) {  
         if (err) {  
            console.log("Error:", err);}  
        });  

        request.addParameter('Username', TYPES.VarChar, username);  
        request.addParameter('Email', TYPES.NVarChar, email);  
        request.addParameter('PasswordHash', TYPES.VarChar, password);  
        request.on('row', function(columns) {  
            columns.forEach(function(column) {  
              if (column.value === null) {  
                console.log('NULL');  
              } else {  
                console.log(" New Signup " + column.value);  
              }  
            });  
        });
        request.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount, more) {
    });
        connection.execSql(request);  
    });
    }

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

The file is supposed to create the local node server and connect to SQL Server. Then it should wait for requests from a webpage with signup. Once it receives a request, it will send it to SQL Server.
The current issue is that it connects and creates the local node server, but immediately goes to a final state and does not allow for new requests. The SQL Server config might be wrong with the SentLogin7WithStandardLogin, but I have not been able to find any resources on any of this.
I am new to SQL Server / nodejs and any help would be appreciated!
Whenever I try and run this using connection debugging, I get these messages:
Server running on port 3000
debug: connected to XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug: State change: Connecting -> SentPrelogin
debug: State change: SentPrelogin -> SentLogin7WithStandardLogin
Connected
debug: State change: SentLogin7WithStandardLogin -> Final
debug: connection to XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX closed
debug: State is already Final



Try Encrypt: true, if it don't works try to see the logs of your SQL databases.
Try it too to help debug:

connection.on('connect', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Connection Failed: ", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Connected");
        ExecuteFunction();
    }
});

Hope this help !

I see nothing in the config to indicate a username or password (or trusted connection) for the database connection, but I'll assume that's removed on purpose.
One thing is the "Trust Server Certificate" option is not really part of the authentication process. It's only used when encrypting the traffic if the certificate SQL Server uses wouldn't otherwise be trusted. You don't need to use set this option at all if encrypt is false... which is also the default, so you can just remove both of those items.
Put it together like this:
var config = {  
    server: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',  //update me
    authentication: {
        type: 'default',
        options: {
            username: "XXXXX",
            password: "XXXXX",
        }
    },
    options: {
        database: 'XXXXXXX',  //update me
        port: XXXXXXX
    }
};

Another issue is the request.addParameter lines should match the name for the parameter variables from the SQL sttring, rather than the columns:
request.addParameter('@username', TYPES.VarChar, username);  
request.addParameter('@email', TYPES.NVarChar, email);  
request.addParameter('@password', TYPES.VarChar, password);  

Also, note the column name is PasswordHash, not just "Password". That "Hash" addition is important. You MUST create a hash of the password using a secure algorithm such BCrypt or SCrypt. This is too important to do wrong even for learning/practice/proof of concept projects!
